# XV11 Producing poor maps with gmaping

Tags: ros, navigation, xv-11, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I purchased an XV11 Neato "Lidar" from "GetSurreal", this one specifically: http://www.getsurreal.com/product/xv-lidar-all-in-one-package a few months ago.

However I was unable to create a usable map using ROS Gmapping. I can navigate an existing map made with the ASUS Xtion, but trying to use the XV11 Lidar to create a map in ROS was impossible.

Reading through the posts it sounds like some people here are using the XV11 Lidar with ROS Gmapping.

Rather than try to explain the issue, I will include a picture
Can anyone point me to what I might be doing wrong that is causing this?

Here is what a map of the room using the ASUS 3D camear looks like:
[image description http://ekpyroticfrood.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/AsusMap.png](http://ekpyroticfrood.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/AsusMap.png)

Here is what the XV11 produces:
[image description http://ekpyroticfrood.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/xv11.png](http://ekpyroticfrood.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/xv11.png)

Notice how the ASUS makes neat clean walls, while the XV11 produces odd dotted lines that eventually spread apart.

Note that both are mounted on the robot, so odometry and everything else is exactly the same. The only difference is their height.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220599/xv11-producing-poor-maps-with-gmaping/) by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2015-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look into the variable **minimumScore**.  see this [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/202196/good-map-with-hector_mapping-and-with-odometry-only-poor-map-with-gmapping/?comment=202632#post-id-202632) it goes into a lot more detail.

It even show some other gmapping options that works good with the xv11 laser.

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2015-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1